# Why does my date & time look like this? "9132128677"

Tags: string, vba

The data in the Excel cell looks like this:

```
5/17/05 19:23:14
```

Then I used this code:

```
Dim strString As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim strTime As String

strString = Sheet5.Range("A" & x)   'Where Range(A,x) contain the time stamp mentioned above
```

The result in the Locals window is this:

```
strString = "9132128677"
```

Why does this happen?

How can I get strDate to equal 5/17/05, and strTime to equal 19:23:14?

My idea was to do this:

```
Sub SplitValue(strString As String, strDate As String, strTime As String)

    Dim varSplit As Variant

    varSplit = Split(strString, " ")

    strDate = varSplit(0)
    strTime = varSplit(1)

End Sub
```

But first I need to understand why the date & time shows up as "9132128677".  Can anyone explain?

Comment: I cant reproduce that at all, excel dates in numeric form are floating point numbers, what specific format is the cell, is it a formula result? - .Text will give you the displayed content but could break on different date formats

Comment: Alex K.  I think you're on to something.  I can't assign that strString to a date using CDate.  How do I find out what format it's in?  It is not a result of a formula, but rather it was generated from an Adobe file using AbleToExtract, a program that converts PDF data into Excel format.

Comment: ahh....I can format it properly this way.  How do I make your comment the answer to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click -> format cells to set an explicit format, or use `.Text` to get the value as its displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a timestamp, it is the number of seconds that have passed since a predetermined date usually January 1, 1970.

Comment: If `9132128677` were the number of seconds since 1970, it would represent a time in the year 2259.  If it represents the current time, then it refers to an epoch some time in the year 1722.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/formating-dates-and-times-vb6

Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss")

Comment: i don't know why someone -1'ed this comment.  i actually found this tutorial somewhat helpful.

Comment: They didn't like my answer. Alex K's answer as well as mine both work :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but answers that are simply links to other websites are generally disliked. What happens if that site is down or inaccessible? You'd get more upvotes if you quoted the part of the article that you think is helpful.